# How to convert for loop into function in r?

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I'd like to create a function to scape web URL data list which includes for loop:

```
news_url <- c()
news_date <-c() 
for (date_i in DATE){
for (page_i in PAGE){
  dt <- format(as.Date(date_i,origin="1970-01-01"), "%Y.%m.%d")
  naver_url <- paste0(naver_url_1,QUERY,naver_url_2,dt,naver_url_3,dt,naver_url_4,page_i)
  html <- read_html(naver_url)
  temp <- unique(html_nodes(html,'#main_pack')%>% 
                   html_nodes(css='.news ')%>%     
                   html_nodes(css='.type01')%>%
                   html_nodes('a')%>%
                   html_attr('href'))
  news_url <- c(news_url,temp)
  news_date <- c(news_date,rep(dt,length(temp)))
}
}
```

Would you let me know how to code it?

Comment: Is the above code what you already have and you are asking for some small adjustments to the current code?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to make some changes in the `output` based on what data you get from `dt` and `temp` and how you want your final output to look like. However, something like this should help.

```
library(rvest)

scrape_page <- function(x, y) {

 dt <- format(as.Date(x,origin="1970-01-01"), "%Y.%m.%d")
 naver_url <- paste0(naver_url_1,QUERY,naver_url_2,dt,naver_url_3,dt,naver_url_4,y)
 html <- read_html(naver_url)
 temp <- unique(html_nodes(html,'#main_pack')%>% 
               html_nodes(css='.news ')%>%     
               html_nodes(css='.type01')%>%
               html_nodes('a')%>%
               html_attr('href'))
  return(list(news_date = dt, news_url = temp))
}
```

and then use

```
output <- lapply(DATE, function(x) lapply(PAGE, function(y) scrape_page(x, y)))
```